# How to take a picture and save it to the app locally with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I'm working on an app where in the current stage when a user takes a picture the picture will be stored locally within the app.

```
 @IBAction func CameraAction(sender: UIButton) {
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    //Save image
    let img = UIImage()
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "myImageKey")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    NSLog("Image stored?")
    viewDidLoad()


}
```

From what I have above, my iPhone opens up its camera and I can take a picture. When I hit capture and the "use this image" option I don't think it the pictures are actually being stored because I haven't been able to recall the pictures.

So I'm asking for help in how to locally store a picture taken from the UIImagePickerController, possibly in the documents folder, how to recall it, and how to do it **without NSUserDEfaults**. Thanks.

Comment: I would not recommend storing images in NSUserDefaults: the size of the image will cause crashes and enormous performance problems.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that I saw that it wasn't recommended. I'm looking for alternative methods of storing images I guess. Thanks.

Comment: You don't use the UIImage image for didFinishPickingImage. Shouldn't it be there?

Answer (score 9):

This is how you would store an image in NSUserDefaults:

> As  I mentioned in my comment, this is not recommended and, if used for more than one image, may result in serious performance loss and even crashes.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
let pngImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) 
            
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(pngImage, forKey: "image")
```

and to retrieve the image:

```
var retrievedImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image") as! AnyObject
```

Then, to display the image:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(data: retrievedImage as! NSData)
```

> This is how to store an image to a file (much better):

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
    
    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    //let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)   // if you want to save as JPEG
    let result = pngImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    
    return result
    
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
saveImage(image, path: imagePath)
```

Then, to retrieve the image, use this function:

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
    
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    
    if image == nil {
        
        print("missing image at: \(path)")
    }
    print("Loading image from path: \(path)") // this is just for you to see the path in case you want to go to the directory, using Finder.
    return image
    
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
image = loadImageFromPath(imagePath)
        imageView.image = image
```

For more details, take a look at http://helpmecodeswift.com/image-manipulation/saving-loading-images

> Also, you don't actually use the image that gets selected in your example, as Frederik pointed out.
>
> You save an empty variable 'img' that has not been assigned to. You need to save 'image', the variable you get back after the picker has finished.

**Here is how you get the image:**

This function returns the variable 'image'

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

> You can then go ahead and just use it e.g.

```
imageView.image = image
```

or maybe

```
 saveImage(image, path: imagePath)
```

Good luck!

Comment: When calling the saveimage function, what variable would I use for the UIImage? I don't know where or when I would define a UIImage variable that I guess comes from the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @acday You already have the variable: it is provided by the function and has the name 'image'

Answer (score 2):

Use this Method: with your image argument as below:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagePicked, nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly well for me in Swift 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
let fileDirectory : NSURL  = {
       return try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory , inDomain: .UserDomainMask , appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
   }()


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    //save to album 
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

   //or to documents 
   //If you want to use png you have to change it later in saveImageToDocumentMethod in the guard statement
   saveImageToDocuments(image, filenameWithExtension: "test.jpg")
}


func saveImageToDocuments(image: UIImage, fileNameWithExtension: String){

       let imagePath = fileDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(fileNameWithExtension)")

       guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) else {
           // handle failed conversion
           print("jpg error")
           return
       }
       imageData.writeToFile((imagePath.path)!, atomically: true)

   }
```

When you want to use that image all you need to do is use the imagePath again and convert it into a UIImage.