# When changing an image with UIImagePickerController the image changes then the app goes back to previous page?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

i am struggling with changing a profile picture on xcode. Ive managed to get the app to change a UIImageView with photo from the photo library on IOS however when i select the image, it changes then goes backwards a UIViewController/previous view.

Im not sure why it is doing this and where i have gone wrong in the code? can someone help?

```
import UIKit

class ProfileScreenVC: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var imgProfilePic: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func ChangeProfile(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let PPimage = UIImagePickerController()
        PPimage.delegate = self
        PPimage.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        PPimage.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(PPimage, animated: true)
        {
            // After it is complete
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
        {
            if let PPimage = info [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
            {
            imgProfilePic.image = PPimage
            }else{
                //Error Message
            }

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Make image circular
        imgProfilePic.roundedImages()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

I also get this error/output when this happens too.

errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dismissing your `UIViewController` dismiss just `UIImagePickerController` (in this case you can use one of the method parameters: `picker`)

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This may be a lot to ask as ive done some searching and cant find much. Now i have the image selected for the profile pic. How do i now save that as the users photo? do i need to have a database that saves to that profile or can i do that in app?

Comment: @CallumRonney man, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please accept my answer back if it helped (and it helped) and if you have another questions, ask another question

Comment: @CallumRonney But you can look for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979323/10253094